# How can I convert a file consisting of key/value pairs to a CSV?

Tags: awk

I have the following text file:

```
$ cat abc.txt
URL: bbc.com
Address:        10.10.10.5#53
Address: 1.1.1.1
Address: 6.6.6.6
URL: cdn.com
Address:        10.10.10.10#53
Address: 2.2.2.2
URL: ngo.com
Address:        10.10.10.5#53
Address: 3.3.3.3
Address: 4.4.4.4
Address: 5.5.5.5
```

I would like to generate the following output:

```
URL:           Server          Resolved      
bbc.com        10.10.10.5#53    1.1.1.1,6.6.6.6
cdn.com        10.10.10.10#53   2.2.2.2
ngo.com        10.10.10.5#53    3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4,5.5.5.5
```

I tried this:

```
awk 'ORS=($1 ~ "URL:")?",":"\n"' abc.txt
```

But it doesn't give me what I want. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought is that `URL:` is used as `RS`, so we can get three records from abc.txt. Then only print odd field of one record. Hope it helps you out.
 :)

```
$ cat  abc.awk
BEGIN{
    RS="URL:";
}

{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)
    {
        if (i<=3)
            printf("%s\t", $i)
        else if (i>3 && i<NF)
            printf("%s, ", $i)
        else
            printf("%s\n", $i)
    }
}

$ awk -f abc.awk abc.txt
bbc.com 10.10.10.5#53   1.1.1.1, 6.6.6.6
cdn.com 10.10.10.10#53  2.2.2.2
ngo.com 10.10.10.5#53   3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4, 5.5.5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to think about this much right now but start with this and see if you can work out the rest:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
     /URL/ { printf "%s%s%s", (NR>1?ORS:""), $2, OFS; c=0; next }
     { printf "%s%s", $2, (c++?",":OFS) }
     END { print "" }
' abc.txt
bbc.com 10.10.10.5#53   1.1.1.1,6.6.6.6,
cdn.com 10.10.10.10#53  2.2.2.2,
ngo.com 10.10.10.5#53   3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4,5.5.5.5,
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.